# How do I use JQuery to find the selected index on a DOM select object?

Tags: jquery, select

Given the following javascript:

```
function foo(selectControl) { ... }
```

and the following html:

```
<select onchange="foo(this)"> ...
```

In JQuery, how do I simulate the following functionality:

```
$('#selectList :selected').text();
```

when instead, I am passing around the real DOM object. I know I can wrap the DOM object up and invoke operations like

```
$(selectControl).val();
```

but I'm specifically asking how to replicate JQuery's string selector mechanism:

```
$('#selectList :selected')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *context* argument of the jQuery function:

```
$(':selected', selectControl).text();
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/eneje/2).

Although I would recommend you to bind the events programmatically:

```
$('#selectID').change(function () {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to do this natively, without jQuery?  I believe it would be:

```
selectControl.options[selectControl.selectedIndex]
```

and then `.value` or `.text` off of that.

Comment: Is there really a "text" attribute on `<option>` tags? I guess there might be.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you grab the select element:

```
var select = document.getElementById('selectId');
```

You can get the text of the selected option like this:

```
var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

(Yes that gets the HTML, but you could dig down and get the text node contents if you wanted.)